# Python Pandas match values from multiple csv and return difference

Tags: python

I have multiple CSV with the same structure

```
CSV_IT

id, name, color
1,john,red
2,marc,blue
3,lisa,white
4,logan,green
```

```
CSV_EN

id, name, color
1,john,red
2,marc,blue
4,logan,green
```

```
CSV_DE

id, name, color
1,john,red
2,marc,blue
3,lisa,white
4,logan,green
5,margie,purple
```

I would like to compare CSVs for ID and extract the ID that do not match and have a percentage of similarity between the various CSV

Results

```
id 1,2,4 in all CSV
id 3 in CSV_IT and CSV_DE
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What have you tried? Can you give a small workable example? We need more input here.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written any code? Are you getting any errors? Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).